# How to look up an AMI ID for use with the L1 CfnInstance construct?

Tags: aws-cdk

I want to look up an AMI ID so that I can create an instance.

I'm forced to use the L1 constructs, and so I can't do it using `LookupMachineImage`:

```
    name = f'{name_prefix}-Workstation'
    ec2_instance = ec2.CfnInstance(
        self,
        name,
        instance_type=ec2.InstanceType('t2.micro'),
        image_id=ec2.LookupMachineImage(name='AmazonLinux2-x86-Development-Workstation-Recipe*'),
        subnet_id=public_subnet_e.ref,
        security_groups=[webserver_sec_group],
        availability_zone='us-east-1e',
        tags=[core.CfnTag(key="Name", value=name)]
    )
```

That throws an error:

```
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError: 
  Error: Expected a string, got {"$jsii.byref":"@aws-cdk/aws-ec2.LookupMachineImage@10061"}
```

I can only make it work by manually looking up the AMI ID and pasting it into the code.  Which is a little silly.  I'm tempted to start writing my own lookup code since that would be simple ... but then why am I using the CDK if I have do do things like that?  I feel like I'm missing something simple?

I would prefer to use the L2 constructs in the CDK, but I can't because they're based on opinions that don't work for me.  Specifically, the L2 `VPC` construct doesn't have a way to limit it to specific availability zones.  Not all instance types are available in all availability zones, so I'm forced to use `CfnVPC` instead so that I can control which availability zones it creates subnets for.

I've been reading the documentation on this for hours, and it seems like there are at least two ways of doing this lookup.  But neither seems to work.  I suspect that I have a conceptual problem rather than a syntax problem?  I'm fairly new to the CDK, coming from SAM / CloudFormation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:
`image_id=ec2.LookupMachineImage(name='AmazonLinux2-x86-Development-Workstation-Recipe*').get_image(self).image_id`

Comment: I had actually figured that out myself from the documentation, but I incorrectly thought that it still wasn't working.  What happened is that it did work, but then I ended up getting a different confusing error from CloudFormation about the parameters I was giving to the CfnInstance constructor.  After I saw your answer I tried again and worked through it.